# Bootstrap 4 continer-fluid class not allowing divs with position relative

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, containers, css-position, sticky

I have a div with position relative having a child div with position sticky (sticky within only relative div).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 bg-info">
      <div style="height:500px;width:100%;" class="position-relative">
        <div class="position-sticky" style="width:100px;height:100px;top:61px;">
          sticky
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use bootstrap 4 class container-fluid, sticky div do not remain sticky anymore, works fine under bootstrap 4 container class though

Comment: i'll appreciate if someone can provide some solution

Comment: For me, both seems to work fine, is it happening for any screen size ?

Comment: @MaxiGui Thanks for replying. I am currently using it on *-md-* screen size. But it is not working with container-fluid for some unknown reason.

Comment: @MaxiGui Since you said that it is working for you in both bootstrap4 classes Container and Container-fluid, I rechecked and found Container-fluid class to be updated in page style tag. Now its really working. How can this be added into knowledge (as answered).

If using a framework like bootstrap, always consider to check if it is locally edited in page

Comment: You can If you found your answered in stackoverflow, you can set it as duplicate. if it is out resourced, you can answered to your own question